# Update value of a Recyclerview with Webservice response

Tags: java, android, web, asynchronous, android-recyclerview

I have a complex problem here.

I initialize my RecyclerView with some datas but asynchronously I'm getting data from my Webservice and I want to use those data in order to have them in my RecyclerView but it's "too late" because my RecyclerView is already initialized.

Here is some code :

First of all I'm initializing my Recyclerview with some datas

```
JSONArray medias; <- Global variable
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider(); <- Global variable where I'm doing my request

public void performRequest()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
         JSONObject newElem = new JSONObject();
         newElem.put("path", "test");
         newElem.put("state", "ongoing");
         newElem.put("name", "element " + j);
         medias.put(newElem);
         serviceProvider.addMedia(getActivity(), new CallbackInterface() {
          @Override
          public void callbackaddMedia(Boolean success, JSONObject obj) {
             if (success && obj != null)
             {
                //Here I want to use the response object like
                //Update medias item state by obj.optString("state");
             }
          }
       });
   }
   initRecyclerView();
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    adapter = new DocumentsAdapter(getActivity(),false, medias, this);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    binding.recyclerAll.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    binding.recyclerAll.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    binding.recyclerAll.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And like I said , Asynchronously I'm calling a Webservice which send me a response like this with each time a different mediaId and state :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "mediaId": "307",
    "state": "success"
}
```

Comment: Hi Manu, you should read carefully the Android docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview , they show you how to handle data asynchronously. This is something built in to the RecyclerView. Look at `RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Hi @PFuster , thank you , I'm trying to use this method , but does it works for notify when a specific value of an Item changed ? it doesn't seems

Comment: Notify your recyler view after getting API response. Update your list and call notifydatasetchange() method of recyclerview

Comment: @Priyankagb Ok thanks , I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it has been said in comment , I used method notifyDataSetChanged() like this :

```
for (int k = 0; k < medias.length(); k += 1) {
    JSONObject mediaObject = (JSONObject) medias.opt(k);
    if (mediaObject.optString("gUid").equals(obj.optString("guid"))) {
        mediaObject.put("state", obj.optString("state"));
        mediaObject.put("id", obj.optString("mediaId"));
        mediaObject.put("path", obj.optString("path"));
        if (getActivity() != null) {
         getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         if (adapter != null) {
         // I'm on my Fragment so I call my adapter like this , If you want to do this on your adapter , just call notifyDataSetChanged();
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
       }
      });
     }
    break;
   }
  }
```

I just updated one by one items of my JSONArray "medias" sent in my RecyclerView Adapter.
And then after that , I just called notifyDataSetChanged() on MAINTHREAD . It will automatically update all values in my JSONArray and so change values on my layout